# Django ModelForm select type form with empty_label not Showing in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

here my forms.py

```
class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = '__all__'
        labels = {'company': 'Company ', }
        empty_labels = {'company': 'Select Company ', }

class InventoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(label='Nama ', max_length=255)
    employee = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        label='Employee ',
        empty_label="Select Employee",
        to_field_name="id",
        queryset=Employee.objects.all(),
        required=False,
        )

    class Meta:
        model = Inventory
        fields = '__all__'
```

on my code, both class trying to set `empty_label` for my `select` type form.

but on `EmployeeForm` it is not showing. there no `empty_label` on `class Meta`?...

how should I do if want use `class Meta` with `emply_label` like second class.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to explicitly define the `company` field in `EmployeeForm`, while keeping the `Meta` class, just like you have done in `InventoryForm`:

```
class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    employee = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        label='Employee ',
        empty_label="Select Employee",
        to_field_name="id",
        queryset=Employee.objects.all(),
        required=False,
    )        
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = '__all__'
```

Widgets, labels etc. can be set as `widgets = {...}` and `labels = {...}` in the `Meta` class.

Comment: @DickyRaambo No, there isn't.

Comment: @DickyRaambo you can find list of al meta options here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.0.5/django/forms/models.py#L193